# Как удалить значок MegaDrive (МегаДиск) из области навигации проводника Windows

Tags: windows, реестр, navigationbar, explorer, проводник

Не так давно решил использовать использовать место на диске от мегафона (МегаДиск), но возникли некоторые неприятности с десктопной версией клиента. А в частности, неудобный неубираемый значок МегаДиска в области навигации проводника, а также в избранных. В обоих этих местах ярлыки мегадиска мне не нужны, но приложение не имеет нужных настроек.

**Каким образом можно удалить значки мегадиска из области навигации и папки избранных?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом, было ясно, что решается проблема через реестр, но конкретный ключ я не знал ранее. После некоторого времени проб без результата, я наткнулся на следующий ключ:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{773775E6-22EF-4902-BE72-F33DAC131D04}
```

Здесь как раз и прописано закрепление надоедливого значка. В этом разделе будет параметр, имя которого содержит `IsPinnedTo`. В нём будет прописана единица. Чтобы отключить значок мегафон-диска, нужно прописать 0 и сохранить, а также перезапустить проводник Windows.

Однако, важно заметить, что это не поможет надолго. В моём случае приложение Мегафона после автозапуска вновь прописывает в редактированный параметр единицу и пункт в проводнике вновь появляется (даже если удалить весь раздел `{773775E6-22EF-4902-BE72-F33DAC131D04}`, Мегафон его снова создаст при следующем запуске). Выхода я вижу только 2:

1. Создать задачу в планировщике, которая будет редактировать реестр и перезапускать проводник
2. Найти в программе МегаДиск фрагмент, который отвечает за данное редактирование реестра и отключить этот фрагмент (наблюдение=>дизассемблирование=>редактирование в HEX-редакторе). Это слишком трудозатратно и ненадёжно, как по мне.

По итогу, я выбрал первый вариант. Удаление иконки мегадиска из избранных производится аналогично: в планировщике создана задача, которая отрабатывает при входе пользователя (но с задержкой в 5 минут) - она запускает bat-файл, в котором прописана команда del для ярлыка в избранных. Да, костыль, но иначе никак - настроек-то у программы почти нет.

---

**P.S.** Грузил я в облако бэкапы и, должен сказать, долгое это дело. Ну представьте: сотня гигов передаётся со скоростью в 1 МБ/с (не превышает), хотя линия 100-мегабитная и диск не настолько медленный. Обратил я внимание, что мой HDD занят при копировании на все 100% при скорости около 10 МБ/с (казалось бы, куда эта скорость, если скорость отдачи у приложения в 10 раз ниже), хотя скорость при последовательном считывании у моего диска около 80 МБ/с.

Стал разбираться, что же этот мегадиск делает при помощи программы `procmon` и выяснил, что, в основном, терзает диск мой только. Он постоянно открывает и закрывает мой файл, считывая по 64 килобайта! Наверное, не удивительно, что при таком подходе время диска уходит в сотню процентов при очень низкой скорости получения информации. Конечно, мне всё равно не понятно, почему же тогда диспетчер выдаёт мне пресловутые 10 МБ/с, но с этим разберусь как-нибудь потом. А пока что я решил делить бэкапы при загрузке в облако на части по 4 гига, чтобы за один сеанс мегадиск хоть пару-тройку частей загрузить успел.

Comment: Должен добавить, что даже разбиение на части помогает лишь отчасти. Если разбить большой файл на части и сразу всё поместить в папку синхронизации, то ничего хорошего не получится, так как МегаДиск начнёт пытаться синхронизировать сразу всё. Для решения этой проблемы уже придётся писать программу, которая будет отслеживать сетевую активность МегаДиска и при отсутствии таковой, добавлять в папку синхронизации ещё один небольшой файл. Желательно, около гигабайта или меньше.
Лично я в итоге отказался от МегаДиска.

Answer (score 0):

Папка(значок) из панели навигации удаляется простым снятием галочки Настройки-Общие-Включить интеграцию с проводником Windows.
Поэтому в реестре и создается этот ключ, что интеграция включена. Может сначала лучше изучить софтину, чем сразу лезть в реестр? [image: Настройка интеграции]

Про копирование. Провайдер Дом.ру - киношка в 6,5 гигов заливается 10-11 мб/сек (80-90 мбит/сек), т.е. почти по потолку тарифного плана...Никакой нагрузки на диск практически нет. На процессор нет. Windows 10 21H2. Антивирус Авира.

Comment: Интересно... Когда пробовал пользоваться МегаДиском, у меня никаких серьёзных настроек не было. Точно ли речь идет о диске от Мегафон? То есть, именно об [этом](https://drive.megafon.ru/) диске?

Comment: По иконке Вашего клиента похоже, что это [другой сервис](https://mega.dp.ua/).